# Delete named column from transactions

Tags: r, arules

I have a transaction object `trans` created using `read.transaction()`. How do I delete a named column from `trans`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular matrix subsetting. If you want to get rid of column 3 in `trans` then you just say:

```
trans <- trans[,-3]
```